# Can I copy & paste documentation from Google or other sources?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Would it be wrong if a user copy-pastes the example from https://developer.google.com ? But of course, I explain more using comments and add text. Will it be wrong?

Comment: It would be wrong without proper attribution. Don't just copy/paste examples, that's absurd. If you're planning on coping the existing documentation verbatim, **please don't**. In doing so, the documentation would need to be maintained in two locations and the unofficial documentation would may become obsolete and wrong any time new changes are introduced to the official documentation.

Comment: No, not THAT lazy. I mean I get the example from google, and I add comments and text to the documentation to make it more clear, would this be wrong?

Answer (score 26):

***Please*** do not copy/paste from other sources. If we do that, then we're simply (and largely) just duplicating the problem that we've set out to solve, which is to give developers *better* documentation than what's currently available.

Some documentation *is* really good, and if you want to build upon that, you can *lightly* use examples from other official sources (e.g. Apple, Google, etc) - but make sure that *most* of what you submit is your own.

Stuff that borrows too heavily from outside sources can / probably will be removed (*especially* if there's no attribution), so take care to try to make all that you contribute mostly your own.

Comment: This needs to be starred somewhere. This Q&A would be useful as a first `faq-proposed` for Documentation

Comment: Consider making this philosophy somewhat more visible for all of the users you're in the process of shunting over to Docs right now. I see no evidence that anyone knows this, nor does the Docs tour say anything of the kind.

Comment: I've shared this in chat (so it's easy to find and point out to folks).

Comment: I agree with @CodyGray - I think this is really, really important to emphasise loud & early, because it's confusing what purpose SE Documentation is exactly built to fit. People need to know that this is *not* a one-stop shop for documentation like, say, DevDocs, but is instead built to *complement* existing docs. I'd even go so far as ensuring that each tag has prominent UI links to the official / best existing documentation - even tying in answers that cite the official docs with special UI for navigating to that section in the official docs' page. There's a lot of risk of duplication here.