# Should we be redocumenting common language guidance?

Tags: discussion, documentation

In the Python documentation, there is a requested topic for [PEP8](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/topic-requests/1397). For those that aren't aware, this is the [style guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for Python. The official guidelines contain examples of what code should and should not look like.

Is re-documenting this kind of information the intended purpose?

Comment: I will calmly leave this link here, yes this one [Would it be wrong if I get my example from Google's dev page for the documentation?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328581)

Comment: Ugh... it was created..

Comment: "This document gives coding conventions for the Python code comprising the standard library in the main Python distribution."  PEP8 is intended only to describe the rules for a particular source base, not the rules for correct Python.  Is "how to write code for a particular specialized source code base" something that SO Docs really needs to cover?

Answer (score 7):

Remember that the goal of docs is *making sure developers have documentation that serves them well*. When it comes to pretty much *any* part of how a language is explained, you can ask:

- Is this easy to understand? Can I read this and just go do what it's explaining?
- Are there common pitfalls that I and others fell in because the 'wrong' way wasn't well explained?
- Can someone working on real-world stuff relate well to the examples?
- Is the reasoning behind things explained well where it needs to be?

.. if the answer to any of that is "no", then make something better :) If it's all "yes", then there's not really much to do.

Comment: But what if someone else is creating the topic although the answer is no? Should we then delete it or let it stay?